# React native render different data in debugging and normal mode

Tags: javascript, react-native

I tried to convert data and then render it.
Like that:

```
render() {
  var user = this.state.user;

  var date = new Date('' + user.birthday.month+'/'+user.birthday.day+'/2017');
  var month = date.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "long" });

  return (
  <View style={styles.info}>
    <Text style={styles.bday}>{month} {user.birthday.day} </Text>
  </View>)}
```

And month gives me result like full date format 'Tue Mar 7 00:00:00 2017', but if I tried it in debug mode, which is very slow running I get appropriate value of month name "March". I tried put this conversion code into separate function and invoke it in JSX, into module, into componentWillMount, but everywhere I got the same result from this getting month name function.
Also I tried to use moment.js, and it gave me right value in debug mode and "undefined" in normal. 
What's the difference? Is it render faster then calculate function? I have other function execution in JSX and it works fine...

Comment: No, unless your calculation code is Async, render should wait your code to finish executing to return JSX. Can you further share your code for me to reproduce?